# Resetar Auto-increment SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Bom dia,

Criei uma tabela nova no SQLServer e estou testando alguns scripts para popular a tabela e me deparei com a seguinte situação, nos meus testes estou fazendo o insert na tabela conferindo as informações e se não estiverem de acordo eu faço um delete na tabela, só que quando faço isso o campo id que é auto incremental não está zerando, ele está continuando do id onde parou, por exemplo: Se eu inclui 10 registros o id auto-incremental vai estar em 10 se eu fizer um delete nos registros da tabela e fizer um outro insert ele começa com 11 ao inves de começar com 1, alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Link Util: http://antoniocampos.net/2012/04/18/sql-server-reiniciar-contador-de-campo-auto-increment/

Comment: Link Relacionado: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simulei a sua pergunta da seguinte forma

- Fiz o `insert` de 83 registros em uma tabela

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Deletei os registros da tabela

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Executei o comando para listar em qual valor está o `AUTO_INCREMENT` da tabela

  `SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('TABELA')`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Fiz um `select` para mostrar que a tabela está sem registros

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Utilizei este comando com a tabela sem registros para zerar o `auto-incremental`

  `DBCC CHECKIDENT (TABELA, RESEED, 0)`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Listei qual valor corrente do `AUTO_INCREMENT` da tabela e o mesmo zerou

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Outra alternativa é você executar este comando via `cmd`

  `OSQL -E -S <SERVIDOR> -d <BASE> -Q "DBCC CHECKIDENT('<TABELA>', RESEED, 0)"`

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]